# How to create a loop in Google Sheet till the optimal solution reached?

Tags: excel, loops, google-sheets

I have created a [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VYwLvH1csSoxNgyWmI3TCFk0b9dV1Ctnk6fSLaYg_uQ/edit#gid=0), I need to find optimal values in the cells 'C8' and 'B14'.

To find optimum values in the cell 'C8', it is required to increase the value of 'B8' by 0.01 every iteration till the value reached to the cell 'O8' becomes >=0. In other words the value of 'B8' i.e 8.8 is required to increment by 0.01, therefore an array should be [8.8,8.81, 8.82, ...]. I have to stop the loop when 'O8' becomes greater than equal to zero.

For this, I have build an formula

```
=IF(O8<0, B8+0.01) + IF(O8>=0, C8)
```

But it is not working.

I am triying to increment the values automatically in the cell 'C8' from 'B8', but I am unable to do that with my formula. So please help me to correct it. [Sheet is attached herewith](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VYwLvH1csSoxNgyWmI3TCFk0b9dV1Ctnk6fSLaYg_uQ/edit#gid=0).

[Pic of Excel Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAabe.jpg)

Comment: Try to include sample data as part of your question, otherwise it will be useless to future visitors when, inevitably the link to you googledocs goes dead

Comment: I'm confused by "formula" and "loop" both being in the question. If in Excel for real life, Goal Seek sounds more appropriate than VBA. If a programming logic exercise then there are more appropriate languages than VBA.

Comment: I am apologizing for my poor English skills. You could consider 'script' as substitute for 'formula'. If, I am restrained to use Excel/Google Sheets then I can't do anything more for my real life problems beyond VBA.

Comment: Excel and Googlesheets are different products with some functions that are the same, some just don't exist in the other and some have the same name but the arguments are in different places. Expecting a solution that will be the same in both is a pipe dream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's *[one approach](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VYwLvH1csSoxNgyWmI3TCFk0b9dV1Ctnk6fSLaYg_uQ/edit#gid=1675178999)* added to the sheet. do test it out:

***Cell_C8***:

```
=let(sell_,B8, 
    loop_,lambda(rec_,Σ, 
    if(let(a,A8,b,B8,d,(Σ*a)-(b*a),e,b*a,f,Σ*a,h,e*0.001,i,f*0.001,j,roundup(h+i,0),k,e*0.00018,l,f*0.00018,m,round(k+l,2),g,j+m,pl,d-g,pl >= 0), Σ, rec_(rec_,Σ+0.01))), 
    loop_(loop_,sell_))
```

***Cell_B14***:

```
=let(buy_,C14, 
    loop_,lambda(rec_,Σ, 
    if(let(a,A14,c,C14,d,(c*a)-(Σ*a),e,Σ*a,f,c*a,h,e*0.001,i,f*0.001,j,roundup(h+i,0),k,e*0.00018,l,f*0.00018,m,round(k+l,2),g,j+m,pl,d-g,pl >= 0), Σ, rec_(rec_,Σ-0.01))), 
    loop_(loop_,buy_))
```

[image]

Comment: Cell_B14 is not working. It would be stopped at 8.8 but it goes below 5. In other sheets, use of this formula is looking very difficult...

Comment: B14 should be 8.8 now. Earlier in the test sheet (as in the screenshot) O14 is given an arbitrary value of 1000, so buy price is calculated to be 4.81

Comment: These codes are only executing on Google Sheets not in Excel. Please suggest any script which works on both.